# Pentaho 7.1 PDF wrong diacritc

Tags: linux, pdf, utf-8, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

We have installed new LINUX server for our Pentaho installation, but I am having problem with diacritics in PDF generated files.

For web (HTML), I have set encoding to `utf-8` which is working perfectly.
BUT for PDF encoding `utf-8` is not working. I have "fixed" it on old server by setting up `CP-1250` encoding, but I don't want to use old standard anymore. So I have been trying to fix it.

I have set option in `pentaho-server/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/classes/classic-engine.properties` to

```
org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.pdf.Encoding=UTF-8
```

but PDF versions of report are still ignoring letters with diacritics..

Soo, my thought is, that there must be some PDF encoding setting above this, perhaps some global PDF generator setting or perhaps Java or Linux itself?

Is anyone able to give me a hint where should I look, what to check?

Comment: Please check what font is used in PDF files generated on Linux? The font needs to support the characters you use. And the font needs to be embeddable.

Comment: How do I check it?

Comment: Some pdf viewers allow to list all fonts embedded into PDF. I am sure you can find an info on how to do it in your pdf viewer. Then you'll need to find documentation for the used fonts to check what characters they support. If the fonts don't support diacritics - then this is the issue, so you'll need to redesign your reports for new font, and, possibly, to install a new font on the server that generates reports.

Comment: But the same font is working well in HTML version.

Comment: I am not a web expert, but as far as I know, browsers may perform so called font substitution to determine a font, which will display all required glyphs. You can consult following answer on how to resolve font issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497425/pentaho-dont-generete-pdf-in-utf-8-encoding. Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: @user4637357 is right, font can be culprit, after lot of R&D i have figured out in my current project that "Arial Unicode MS" supports all types of characters, you can try and see whether it works for you or not.